# python ssh script to deal with secondary shell

Tags: python, bash, ssh

I want to write a python script to ssh into a server and print some output. But I have some problem here when coding, here is what I basically want to achieve:

```
[zz@bts01 ~]$ cd /opt/cdma-msc/
[zz@bts01 cdma-msc]$ ./sccli
SoftCore for CDMA CLI (c) Quortus 2010
RAN> show system
System Configuration
  Software version:      V1.31
  System name:           RAN
  System location:
  Shutdown code:
  Emergency call dest:
  Current date/time:     Tue Feb 27 14:27:41 2018
  System uptime:         20h 33m
  Auto-provisioning:     Enabled
RAN> exit
Bye.
[zz@bts01 cdma-msc]$
```

Please see above I only want the show system output.
But problem is I use python paramiko ssh package, looks like it is not recognize the second shell after I execute the  ./sccli command. 
what can I do to allow python ssh script interactive with the second shell (above 'RAN>')?

Thanks!!

Comment: You probably want to do something like [this example](https://github.com/fgimian/paramiko-expect/blob/master/examples/paramiko_expect-demo.py) for `paramiko-expect`

Comment: Alternatively you could also use `twisted` to achieve what you want, but it's probably much more work.

Comment: Save yourself some trouble and run it through fabric: http://www.fabfile.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There exists a python library that was built for running SSH commands from Python. It is pretty powerful and robust. You can run commands across many machines in parallel, it has error handling, can execute as root.. etc. etc.

Check it out: https://github.com/dwighthubbard/sshmap

Learning how to use this library is very valuable if you have to do SSH commands from python frequently.